# How can I have it to where "git push" pushes to local repositories?

Tags: git

I can do `git remote add origin x@x:~/blah` and `git push` will work. But if I create a local copy `git clone ~/blah` inside /var, then `git remote add local /var/blah` inside `~/blah`, when I try `git push` it doesn't push the updates.

How can I make git push updates to local copies?

I have a shared library I use in a bunch of projects. I use `git clone` inside other folders to get a local copy of the library. When I update the main library I have to go to each local copy and type `git pull` to get the updates? How can I say `git push` to push code to all libraries?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, `git push` pushes to origin.  If you want to push to a different remote repository (on the same machine or otherwise), you need to do `git push <remote-name>`.  Also keep in mind what mipadi says about non-bare repositories.

So in your case, after a `git remote add local /var/blah`, you would do `git push local` to push changes to the repo in /var/blah.

A little google-fu came up with this post for pushing to multiple remote repositories at once:

http://web.archive.org/web/20110828185858/http://jeetworks.com/node/22

Essentially, a remote can have multiple urls.  To do this edit your .git/config and put something like this:

```
[remote "all"]
    url = /some/path/to/repo1
    url = /some/path/to/repo2
```

After that, you can do `git push all` to push to both of the remote urls pointed to by the remote "all".

Answer (score 6):

Are you pushing to a non-bare repository? If you are, the repo itself will be updated, but the checked-out (on-disk) files will not be updated.

Comment: I have a shared library I use in a bunch of projects. I use "git clone" inside other folders to get a local copy of the library. When I update the main library I have to go to each local copy and type "git pull" to get the updates? How can I say "git push" to push code to all libraries?